# DateTime precision vs accuracy?

Tags: c#, datetime

Eric Lippert wrote an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx) about DateTime. Jon Skeet commented on his article with

> I don't have a problem with DateTime having too much **precision** so long as everyone knows it. Precision, not accuracy

What does he mean by that?

What does it mean to approach DateTime precision issues, vs. accuracy issues?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

He's using the term accuracy wrong in that article. Poor accuracy really implies a systematic bias, such as what would happen if your computer's clock were off by one minute.  What Lippert's article is really illustrating is [false precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_precision).

In other words, the `DateTime` structure is very precise in that it is capable of representing a difference of only 100 nanoseconds.  However, the values you'll get from  `DateTime.Now` are only precise to within 16 milliseconds.  But the numbers you're given will still carry the full precision that `DateTime` is capable of representing.  That creates a gotcha, since it's easy to assume that `DateTime.Now` is returning values that carry the `DateTime` structure's full precision instead of taking the time to find out what precision is provided by the source from which `DateTime.Now` gets its values.

`DateTime`, being a simple data structure, has no inherent accuracy, so it doesn't really make sense to talk about it.  (What's the accuracy of a kilogram?) Better to talk about how accurate the system clock is.  (e.g., how accurate is that scale?) But that could vary with every computer, and doesn't really have anything to do with data structures in .NET.

Comment: Sure.  In the light of the morning, though, I've got to critique myself too.  A data structure can have an inherent accuracy, to the extent that the highest precision it represents sets a limit on how accurate you can be.  A `DateTime`'s never going to let you work with data that's accurate to 10ns, because you'll lose all of that accuracy the moment you try to stick it in a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem that arises with having that much precision is of course
>   that it is very easy to assume that a given value is as accurate as it
>   is precise. But that’s not warranted at all! I can represent my height
>   in a double-precision floating point number as 1.799992352094 metres;
>   though precise to a trillionth of a metre, it’s only accurate to about
>   a hundredth of a metre because I do not have a device which can
>   actually measure my height to a trillionth of a meter, or even a
>   thousandth of a metre. There is way more precision than accuracy here.

[Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx)

Comment: Well, imagine you have stick with length of 3 cm. You can say that it's length is 3.0000000000001234567543278456783495... it will be precise, but not accurate.